# Get loop value from a method in another class

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates, task

I created a method to copy files and folders, this method is present in a class called *Helper*

```
static void List(string folder)
{
//methods to get files and folders and return IEnumerable

   foreach (var dname in directories)
       Copy(dname);
   foreach (var fname in files)
       Copy(fname);
}
```

which works fine, but I need to show the user the progress (bar or percentage) when he clicks a button in the **MainForm**.

so far I have this code and should add *Task* or similar to get the progress but it needs a loop.

```
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string dir = "Some\\Path";
Helper.List(dir);
}
```

Obviously I cannot track what I cannot count so I was advised using delegates to get values from the other classes method, but I am just starting and I have failed to find some useful help online.
Any help?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). In short, a delegate is a piece of code you can pass as a parameter to a method

Comment: @RandRandom heh yeah that was too quick of a comment of me, I also missed the progress bar part and the problem of not knowing on beforehand the number of files and directories.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do is add a `IProgress<T>` parameter to your List-method. That method should then call the `.Report(T)` method to describe the progress. Your caller should create a [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-6.0) object, and attach an event handler or callback to let the UI know when the progress has advanced.

The actual work needs to be done on a background thread, usually done with a Task.Run,  like:

```
private async void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string dir = "Some\\Path";
  var progress = new Progress<int>(ProgressCallback);
  try{
    await Task.Run(()=> Helper.List(dir, progress ));
  }
  catch{
  // handle failure
  }
}
private void ProgressCallback(int p){
    // Update UI
}

static void List(string folder, IProgress<int> p)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++){
   p.Report(i);
   ...
  }
}
```

My personal preference is to create a custom Progress-object, with features like including things like a description string, and allow it to be split to handle nested loops.

Comment: How do I add progress to the List method?

Comment: @user10191234 - that is basically what the answer is telling you `What you should do is add a IProgress<T> parameter to your List-method.`

Comment: @user10191234 add the IProgress as a parameter & call the report method on it.

Comment: Great but implementing a progress bar in ProgressCallback() is giving me a null pointer exceprion.

Comment: @user10191234 the actual progress bar should be added to your form/control, and *updated* in the progressCallback-method. I'm not sure what you mean by "Implementing a progress bar", but you should not implement, nor create, anything in the callback. You can also show the progress bar in a separate, modal, window, but that require a bit of extra code to make the window close itself once the task completes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps as I see it:

1. Create a progress bar in your view (I'm going to assume you're using WPF)
2. Find out how many files/directories you'll be copying, and set that to your progress bar max
3. Each time you copy a file/directory, increment your progress bar current value
4. Have that change apply to the view

With that written out in English, lets try coding it:

**1. Create the progress bar in the xaml**

```
<ProgressBar Name="progressBar" />
```

**2/3. Set the maximum and increment**

This is hard because your `List` method is static, and inside your `Helpers`

For the time being, I'll write out a method that you can put in your MainWindow.Xaml.cs (or whichever window you're working on), and then you can figure out the best place to change this

```
private void List(string folder)
{
  //methods to get files and folders and return IEnumerable

  var count = directories.Count() +
    files.Count();
  progressBar.Maximum = count;
  foreach (var dname in directories)
  {
    Copy(dname);
    progressBar.Value++;
  }
  foreach (var fname in files)
  {
    Copy(fname);
    progressBar.Value++;
  }
}
```

**4. Make this work on a Thread to prevent the UI from locking**

When calling your `List`, it might be an idea to run that in a task:

```
private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string dir = "Some\\Path";
  Task t = new Task(() => List(dir));
  t.Start();
}
```

But with that running in the background, you'll get an error now as you can't update the progress bar anymore. Not unless we send back our commands via the dispatcher

For this, I tend to create a method to make the calls a little easier:

```
private void UpdateOnView(Action action)
{
  Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
}
```

Then in use:

```
private void List(string folder)
{
  //methods to get files and folders and return IEnumerable

  var count = directories.Count() +
    files.Count();
  UpdateOnView(() => { progressBar.Maximum = count; });
  foreach (var dname in directories)
  {
    Copy(dname);
    UpdateOnView(() => { progressBar.Value++; });
  }
  foreach (var fname in files)
  {
    Copy(fname);
    UpdateOnView(() => { progressBar.Value++; });
  }
}
```

If that updates too quickly, and you want to see your progress bar in action, chuck a `Thread.Sleep(100);` in your loops, and it'll slow things down for ya

Comment: No, I am using Windows Forms, it is an impressive solution but I cannot get the progress be implemented in the Helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-6.0). This allows you to punt that IO work off the main thread and communicate progress to the UI via calling [ReportProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress?view=net-6.0#system-componentmodel-backgroundworker-reportprogress(system-int32)) and handling the [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged?view=net-6.0) event.

Since you are enumerating over the files and directories to copy them, you'll know the total number which you can use to determine the progress percentage as you work through those lists.